# Background image

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo e-mails marketing em HTML, porém estou com problemas no footer, onde tem um background url e na versão mobile ele desconfigura:

[image: versão desktop]

[image: versão mobile]

meu código:

```css
.background-gray2-no-padding {
        background-color: #C4C3C2;
        margin-top: -1em;
    }

    .background-gray2-no-padding div {
        padding-top: 5em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        background-image: url(http://www.tattoosinspiradoras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/footer-14.png);
        /*background-size: 100%;*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        text-align: left !important;
    }

    .background-gray2-no-padding div span {
        color: white;
        font-size: 8pt;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="background-gray2-no-padding">
   <div>
      <!-- <img src="img/footer.png" class="width-100"> -->
      <span>Os serviços de limpeza da  possuem garantia de qualidade comprovada, adequando-se aos termos do artigo 26 do CDC, que rege as condutas de consumo de serviços não duráveis. Dessa forma, as garantias dos serviços de limpeza estão limitados à 30 dias corridos, contados à partir da data de realização do serviço. A partir do trigésimo primeiro dia corrido, por ser impossível o controle das condições de uso dos bens higienizados, mudanças naturais enfrentadas pelo mobiliário e pela ação do tempo, a empresa preservará o seu direito de não reconhecer a relação entre eventuais alterações nos aspectos físicos do estofados e seus serviços de limpeza.</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

como eu resolvo isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente aplicando no `background` do `span` a cor verde da imagem de fundo, e coloque o `span` como `display: inline-block;`. Altere também o `padding-top` da `div` para `9%` e o `background-size: 100% auto;`, entre outros ajustes. Veja o resultado:

```css
.background-gray2-no-padding {
 background-color: #C4C3C2;
 margin-top: -1em;
}

.background-gray2-no-padding div {
   padding-top: 9%;
   background-image: url(http://www.tattoosinspiradoras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/footer-14.png);
   background-size: 100% auto;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   text-align: left !important;
}

.background-gray2-no-padding div span {
   color: white;
   font-size: 8pt;
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0;
   background: #8ccfc3;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-gray2-no-padding">
   <div>
      <!-- <img src="img/footer.png" class="width-100"> -->
      <span>Os serviços de limpeza da  possuem garantia de qualidade comprovada, adequando-se aos termos do artigo 26 do CDC, que rege as condutas de consumo de serviços não duráveis. Dessa forma, as garantias dos serviços de limpeza estão limitados à 30 dias corridos, contados à partir da data de realização do serviço. A partir do trigésimo primeiro dia corrido, por ser impossível o controle das condições de uso dos bens higienizados, mudanças naturais enfrentadas pelo mobiliário e pela ação do tempo, a empresa preservará o seu direito de não reconhecer a relação entre eventuais alterações nos aspectos físicos do estofados e seus serviços de limpeza.</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adicione a propriedade: "background-position: center" a imagem

```css
.background-gray2-no-padding {
        background-color: #C4C3C2;
        margin-top: -1em;
    }

    .background-gray2-no-padding div {
        padding-top: 5em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        background-image: url(http://www.tattoosinspiradoras.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/footer-14.png);
        background-position: center;
        /*background-size: 100%;*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        text-align: left !important;
    }

    .background-gray2-no-padding div span {
        color: white;
        font-size: 8pt;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<div class="background-gray2-no-padding">
            <div>
                <!-- <img src="img/footer.png" class="width-100"> -->
                <span>Os serviços de limpeza da  possuem garantia de qualidade comprovada, adequando-se aos termos do artigo 26 do CDC, que rege as condutas de consumo de serviços não duráveis. Dessa forma, as garantias dos serviços de limpeza estão limitados à 30 dias corridos, contados à partir da data de realização do serviço. A partir do trigésimo primeiro dia corrido, por ser impossível o controle das condições de uso dos bens higienizados, mudanças naturais enfrentadas pelo mobiliário e pela ação do tempo, a empresa preservará o seu direito de não reconhecer a relação entre eventuais alterações nos aspectos físicos do estofados e seus serviços de limpeza.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: funcionou +/-
o texto no mobile tá todo bagunçado =/

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa usar media queries, é como se fosse códigos que voce coloca no css só para os tamanhos de tela que quiser, ex.: celular, tablet...

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { 
   padding-top: 5em;
   ...
}
```

Aconselho a ler https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries